# jQuery checkbox to enable/disable text input and add/remove default value

Tags: jquery, if-statement, input, checkbox, javascript

I am trying to create a small reusable function that will, when checked, disable a text field and insert a default value of '160', and when unchecked, enable the field and remove the value. I have it mostly finished but the unchecking part is throwing me off.

```
$('#chkIsTeamLead').change(function(){


   if ($('#chkIsTeamLead').checked = true){
      $('#txtNumHours').val('160').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      console.log('checked');
   }

  if ($('#chkIsTeamLead').checked = false){
     $('#txtNumHours').val('').removeAttr('disabled');
     console.log('unchecked');
   }

});
```

I had it setup as a reusable function with arguments passed to it but that was giving me more trouble, I would like the arguments to be checkbox, target, and value preferably
link to my current code: http://codepen.io/AlexBezuska/pen/bwgsA
Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Use `$('#chkIsTeamLead').is(':checked')` in your conditions.

Comment: And you must compare two values with `==`.

Comment: And you can use `if(){} else{}` rather than 2 `if`'s

Comment: Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FRQja/1/).

Comment: `I had it setup as a reusable function with arguments passed to it but that was giving me more trouble` What trouble ? Can you post that code where you tried to pass arguments as well ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FRQja/3/)**

1. Use `.is(':checked')`.
2. You must compare two values with `==`.
3. When you are working with attribute like `disabled`, it's better to use `.prop()` method instead of `.attr()`.

---

```
$('#chkIsTeamLead').change(function(){
    if ($('#chkIsTeamLead').is(':checked') == true){
        $('#txtNumHours').val('160').prop('disabled', true);
        console.log('checked');
    } else {
        $('#txtNumHours').val('').prop('disabled', false);
        console.log('unchecked');
    }
});
```

---

References:

- [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) - jQuery API Documentation
- [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) - jQuery API Documentation
- [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) - jQuery API Documentation

Comment: I think `==true` isnt necessary as `if` will work that out by itself

Comment: @passionateCoder Yes, I just left it there for `==` to show OP.

Comment: also , Doug Crockford would [kill](http://youtu.be/hQVTIJBZook) you if you didnt use `===` instead of `==` :P

Comment: @passionateCoder Yesssssss, I love him `;)`.

Comment: This works great, thanks, and thanks for the direction on .prop(), I will have to read this over and learn more about it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#chkIsTeamLead').change(function(){


   if ($('#chkIsTeamLead').is(':checked')){
      $('#txtNumHours').val('160').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      console.log('checked');
   } else {
     $('#txtNumHours').val('');
    $('#txtNumHours').removeAttr('disabled');
     console.log('unchecked');
   }
 });
```